# Não tem o arquivo layout no Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Comecei agora e não achei em nenhum lugar como resolver isso. O arquivo layout desde quando eu baixei não aparece. [o arquivo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjYLj.png)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando um pouco sobre esse problema eu encontrei uma possível solução para o seu problema. Se a pasta não estiver lá ou não foi adicionada automaticamente quando você criou o projeto, você precisa adicioná-la ao seu projeto da seguinte maneira:

- Clique com o botão direito do mouse na pasta res
- Selecione New -> Android Resource Directory
- Selecione o tipo de recurso como layout no pop-up
- Clique OK

Agora que você adicionou sua pasta de layout, pode começar a adicionar arquivos XML a esta pasta seguindo as etapas a seguir:

- Clique com o botão direito do mouse na pasta de layout
- Selecione New -> Android Resource File
- Digite o nome do arquivo
- Selecione o tipo de recurso como layout
- Clique OK

Agora você tem um novo arquivo XML que pode ser usado em qualquer atividade ou fragmento.

Para conferir a resposta original clique [aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48169236/14296786)

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).